# How does flutter make PopupRoute not cover the appbar?

Tags: flutter

The white blocks in the picture popped up using PopopRoute.I need to close this popop by clicking on the appbar.But I found that the appbar seems to be covered, I clicked on it and there is no event response.

[image]

```dart
void showTop() {
     // Get the coordinates of the click control
    final RenderBox button = _buttonKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();
    // Get the coordinates of the bottom left of the control
    var a = button.localToGlobal(Offset(0.0, button.size.height),
        ancestor: overlay);

    // Get the coordinates of the bottom right of the control
    var b = button.localToGlobal(button.size.bottomLeft(Offset(0, 0)),
        ancestor: overlay);
    final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromRect(
      Rect.fromPoints(a, b),
      Offset.zero & overlay.size,
    );
    final RenderBox body = _bodyKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

    showPopupWindow(
      context: context,
      fullWidth: true,
      position: position,
      elevation: 3.0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          NavigatorUtils.goBack(context);
          setState(() {
            isShow = false;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          // color: const Color(0x99000000),
          height: body.size.height,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.white10,
            child: Text("Im Test?"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

## Because the showPopupWindow code is too long, I made a separate link to show it

Url ===> https://cdn.clk528.com/showPopupWindow.dart

Comment: Please put the code in your question.

Comment: Hi bro, I have posted the code.thank u very much!